# How to add paragraph after image within a Slate text editor?

Tags: javascript, richtext, slatejs

I am currently working on rich text editor based on Slate. I need to implement possibility to insert a paragraph right after an image, when image is focused. Now when the image has focus and I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button but nothing happened. It should insert new empty paragraph right after the image.

Same behavior in [this example](https://www.slatejs.org/examples/images).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are selecting a void node (Image node), pressing `enter` won't add a new line by default. The most upvoted answer adds a new line only on image insert, which doesn't address the question.

Here's a plugin on how to give the editor your desired behavior.

```js
import { Editor, Node, Path, Range, Transforms } from 'slate'

export const withCorrectVoidBehavior = editor => {
  const { deleteBackward, insertBreak } = editor

  // if current selection is void node, insert a default node below
  editor.insertBreak = () => {
    if (!editor.selection || !Range.isCollapsed(editor.selection)) {
      return insertBreak()
    }

    const selectedNodePath = Path.parent(editor.selection.anchor.path)
    const selectedNode = Node.get(editor, selectedNodePath)
    if (Editor.isVoid(editor, selectedNode)) {
      Editor.insertNode(editor, {
        type: 'paragraph',
        children: [{ text: '' }],
      })
      return
    }

    insertBreak()
  }
    
  // if prev node is a void node, remove the current node and select the void node
  editor.deleteBackward = unit => {
    if (
      !editor.selection ||
      !Range.isCollapsed(editor.selection) ||
      editor.selection.anchor.offset !== 0
    ) {
      return deleteBackward(unit)
    }

    const parentPath = Path.parent(editor.selection.anchor.path)
    const parentNode = Node.get(editor, parentPath)
    const parentIsEmpty = Node.string(parentNode).length === 0

    if (parentIsEmpty && Path.hasPrevious(parentPath)) {
      const prevNodePath = Path.previous(parentPath)
      const prevNode = Node.get(editor, prevNodePath)
      if (Editor.isVoid(editor, prevNode)) {
        return Transforms.removeNodes(editor)
      }
    }

    deleteBackward(unit)
  }

  return editor
}
```

We override the `insertBreak` behavior (which gets called on carrige return) and insert a blank line instead by calling `Editor.insertNode(editor, blankNode)` if the selected node is void.

We also override the `deleteBackward` behavior. Without the plugin, deleting an empty line right after a void node will delete the node too! Now, instead of deleting the node before, we delete the blank line and select the node before.

To use this plugin, you would do something like:

```js
const editor = useMemo(() => withCorrectVoidBehavior(withReact(createEditor())), []);
```

I stole the plugin code from: https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/issues/3991

Answer (score 9):

Editing the [source](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/master/site/examples/images.tsx) that SlateJS gave, I just added a paragraph node within the `insertImage()` function.

SlateJS Source:

```js
const insertImage = (editor, url) => {
  const text = { text: '' }
  const image = { type: 'image', url, children: [text] }
  Transforms.insertNodes(editor, image)
}
```

Edit To:

```js
const insertImage = (editor, url) => {
  const text = { text: '' }
  const image = [
    { 
      type: 'image', 
      url, 
      children: [text] 
    }, 
    {
      type: 'paragraph',
      children: [text],
    }
  ];

  Transforms.insertNodes(editor, image);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

@asolace 's answer is great for me except I had to make a slight modification because the cursor was not moving.

```
const insertImage = (editor, url) => {
  const text = { text: '' };
  const nodes = [
    {
      type: 'image',
      url,
      children: [text],
    },
    {
      type: 'paragraph',
      children: [text],
    },
  ];

  nodes.forEach((node) => {
    Transforms.insertNodes(editor, node);
  });
};
```